# Returning arrays and accessing values

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and I am trying to return an array from a class function and then access its values like so:

```
  <?php 
    class Foo
        {
            private $access;

            public function setAccess($access)
            {
                $this->access = $access;
            }


            public function getAccess()
            {
                return $this->access;
            }
        }


$var = new Foo();
$var->setAccess(array(1,2,3,4));

$var2 = $var->getAccess()[2];

echo $var2;

?>
```

When I try to run a page with this code, I get the following:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in arraytest.php on line 22
```

How can I access the values for my private arrays in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't call an array value directly like that, you'd have to write this:

```
$access = $var->getAccess();
$var2 = $access[2];
```

alternatively, you could add a function like this to your class.

```
public function getAccessValue($key) {
  return $this->access[$key];
}
```

Comment: Ah, I originally wrote a function like that however I was hoping there was a better method. I will just store the array into a variable first then dereference, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$var2 = $var->getAccess()[2];
```

can't be done in PHP before version 5.4 (this feature is called **array dereferencing**). At the moment you have to do something like this:

```
$var2 = $var->getAccess();
$var2 = $var2[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the PHP version and the name (array dereferencing). I had a hard time finding related questions.